# No html tags are working if the parent tag contain ng-bind-html directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Following is my Code Example, if i removed ng-bind-html then the div is working, if not it fails, please suggest me an answer

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('CartController', function($scope) {
                $scope.title = "<p>hello world</p>";
            $scope.test = "How are you..!How are you..!How are you..!";
        });
  </script>

<body ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-controller="CartController">
    <label ng-bind-html=title> 
        <div>{{test}}</div>
    </label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u use `ng-bind-html` to the `<label>` it completely replaced by the `$scope` variable, so u cannot achieve the `<div>` inside the `<label>` tag if the label contains `ng-bind-html` directive

`<label ng-bind-html='<p>hello world</p>'> Label1 <div>text1</div> </label>`

In the above Html, Only the html "**hello world**" will be displayed along with text1, anyway it is not advisable until it requires..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) injecting `$sce` into the controller:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/b52o8wp9/)

```
app.controller('CartController', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.title = $sce.trustAsHtml("<p>hello world</p>");
    $scope.test = "How are you..!How are you..!How are you..!";
});
```

Of course the HTML `label` will be completely replaced by `$scope.title` and you aren't able to see `{{test}}` anymore

Comment: Just place `{{test}}` outside the label.

Comment: So you need to do everything in the controller check this http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/b52o8wp9/1/

Comment: But i need this to be two different tags... ie. label and div

Comment: Anyway i agree with this point Mr. Michelem, "Of course the HTML label will be completely replaced by $scope.title and you aren't able to see {{test}} anymore"